# Filepath read from a data file

Tags: fortran, filepath

I am trying to read a filepath of unknown length from a data file in fortran. Is there an easy way to do this?

The datafile is like this

```
C:/folder1/folder2/folder3
20.0
22.0
```

I am trying to read it with

```
character(len=100) :: filepath
real :: a, b
open(unit=1,filename='file.dat',status='unknown')
read(1,*) filepath
read(1,10) a
read(1,10) b

10 format(e20.8)
```

So, far this hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

- you need to specify `file=`
- Read into a single string: `read(1,'(a)')`, otherwise the `/` will be interpreted as record markers
- Don't use unit numbers below ~100, especially the ones below 10 are commonly used e.g. for STDIN/STDOUT (highly compiler dependent). If possible, use the `newunit=unit` statement (Fortran 2008).

This is working for me:

```
program test
  implicit none
  character(len=100) :: filepath
  real :: a, b
  open(unit=1000,file='file.dat',status='unknown')
  read(1000,'(a)') filepath
  read(1000,'(e20.8)') a
  read(1000,'(e20.8)') b

  print *,filepath, a, b

end program
```

```
$ ./a.out 
C:/folder1/folder2/folder3 20.0000000 22.0000000
```